# Array of pthread pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pthreads, malloc, realloc

I am trying to dynamically allocate a array of pthread pointers, but get this glibc error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./test: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x00000000084d2010 ***
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    pthread_t **threads;
    int i;

    for(i=1;i<100;i++) {
        threads = realloc(threads, sizeof(pthread_t*)*i);
        threads[i] = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
    }

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should initialize `threads` (emphasis is mine).

> **C11 (n1570), § 7.22.3.5 The realloc function**
>
> If `ptr` is a null pointer, the realloc function behaves like the malloc function for the
>   specified size. *Otherwise, if ptr does not match a pointer earlier
>   returned by a memory  management function, or if the space has been
>   deallocated by a call to the free or realloc function, the behavior is
>   undefined.*

- `sizeof(pthread_t *) * i` doesn't allocate enough memory to access to `thread[i]`. You have to allocate `((sizeof(pthread_t *) * (i + 1))`.

Comment: I just wonder why he's reallocating the array one element larger with every iteration instead of allocating the whole thing once before the for loop.

Comment: I don't understand either. But it seems to be a code extract.

Comment: Great, thanks. This is just an example of some other code where i don't necessarily know how many times i need to realloc.